# Solve equations with variables in denominator

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations like this

$$
\sum_i^n \frac{1}{x+a_i y+b_iz}=S_1,\\
\sum_i^n \frac{a_i}{x+a_i y+b_iz}=S_2,\\
\sum_i^n \frac{b_i}{x+a_i y+b_iz}=S_3,
$$
where $n,a_i,b_i,S_{1,2,3}$ are parameters (known), and I would like to solve $(x,y,z)$. Here $n$ is a big number, such as 100.

Is there any analytical or numerical method to solve this kind equation? Or I used some stupid numerical method and got a solution, is there any method to prove that this equation can have and only have one solution?

Comment: Sometimes there are no solutions, sometimes there are infinitely many solutions. For example, if all $a_i=a$, all $b_i=b$, then the equations become $x+ay+bz=n/S_1=na/S_2=nb/S_3$. If $n/S_1=na/S_2=nb/S_3$ we have infinitely many solutions. If $n/S_1=na/S_2=nb/S_3$ is not satisfied, then there are no solutions.

Comment: @plop Thanks for your reply. Since I use this equations for a real physical system, I know that there must be a solution. Just not sure if there is a standard method to solve this kind equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect a formal solution for this problem.

But, using *stupid* numerical methods

- Newton-Raphson would a good idea (provided you have "reasonable" estimates) - very simple derivatives
- What I would prefer is minimization of the norm
  $$\Phi(x,y,z)=\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x+a_i y+b_iz}-S_1\Bigg]^2+$$
  $$\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{x+a_i y+b_iz}-S_2\Bigg]^2+\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{x+a_i y+b_iz}-S_3\Bigg]^2$$ and you can easily provide the analytical Jacobian and Hessian.